# Operation aborted error on redirect in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer, https, internet-explorer-6

I have a problem in IE6.

I redirect http://example.com to https://example.com using php `header()` function.
It works well in FF and IE > 6 but it gives this error in IE6 in a alert box:

```
The Internet Explorer cannot open https://example.com
Operation abored
```

Why does this error appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of some JS scripts. I added `defer="defer"` to `<script>` tags and the problem was solved.